# Different internet speed when testing by my own code

Tags: android, performance

I am facing a problem in checking of internet speed. Actually I am developing an android app which can test your internet speed on your cell phone. I make an sample to test the speed and its show write speed such as 7.3 Mbps as I am getting from my ISP. But in this test I am using below code.

long startCon = System.currentTimeMillis();
            Log.i("mymobilespeedtest", "start conn = " + startCon);

```
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(imageURL);
        HttpResponse response = null;
        try {
            response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            Log.i("SketchEffect","Executing http connection to download selected image.");
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Log.i("FBAlbum", e.toString());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Log.i("FBAlbum", e.toString());
        }
        long endCon = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Log.i("mymobilespeedtest", "endCon = " + endCon);
```

Now I want to show progress as of internet speed by using a handler and using different method download a file.'

In this method I am using below code

```
         String downloadFileUrl =    "http://www.gregbugaj.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/03/dummy.txt";
          URL    url1 = new URL(downloadFileUrl);
            URLConnection con1 = url1.openConnection();
            con1.setUseCaches(false); stream1 = con1.getInputStream();
            Message msgUpdateConnection = Message.obtain(mHandler,
                    MSG_UPDATE_CONNECTION_TIME);
            msgUpdateConnection.arg1 = (int) connectionLatency;
            mHandler.sendMessage(msgUpdateConnection);

            long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
            int currentByte = 0;
            long updateStart = System.currentTimeMillis();
            long updateDelta = 0;
            int bytesInThreshold = 0;
            int bytesIn = 0;
            while (true) {
                if ((currentByte = stream1.read()) == -1) {
                    break;
                } else {
                    bytesIn++;
                    bytesInThreshold++;
                    baf.append((byte) currentByte);
                    if (updateDelta >= UPDATE_THRESHOLD) {
                        int progress = (int) ((bytesIn / (double) EXPECTED_SIZE_IN_BYTES) * 100);
                        Message msg = Message.obtain(mHandler,
                                MSG_UPDATE_STATUS,
                                calculate(updateDelta, bytesInThreshold));
                        msg.arg1 = progress;
                        msg.arg2 = bytesIn;
                        mHandler.sendMessage(msg);
                        // Reset
                        updateStart = System.currentTimeMillis();
                        bytesInThreshold = 0;
                    }
                    updateDelta = System.currentTimeMillis() - updateStart;
                }

            } if (downloadTime == 0) {
                downloadTime = 1;
            }

            Message msg = Message.obtain(mHandler, MSG_COMPLETE_STATUS,
                    calculate(downloadTime, bytesIn));
            msg.arg1 = bytesIn;
            mHandler.sendMessage(msg);
```

By above code I am getting only .8 or 1.o Mbps speed (In mega bit per secons not bytes)

Comment: If you want to measure download speed you should get rid of the message handling code. Read from the socket and don't store the read bytes anywhere. Right now the speed may be reduced due to bottle-necks in your code.

Answer (score 0):

i'm trying to do the same thing, using a HTTP GET to measure Internet Speed (download), but there is a problem. When you do this: **response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);** you are not measuring only the time that takes for you to receive the answer, you are measuring the time that takes to make the entire request, that means that you are measuring the overhead of the entire protocol like establishing the TCP connection between server and client.

Check this: http://tinypic.com/r/15u6og/8

The useful data that you want are the PDU's, the rest is just overhead. But you are measuring the entire thing. As you can see establishing the TCP connection takes a lot of time.

That's why you are getting a wrong value.

I know this is a little late, but have you resolved this yet?

Comment: thanks for your help. Actually I didn't get any solution rather then socket programming which is really big time taken that's why I skip this stuff. For this project time matter a lot comparison to this feature.